# Android studio java can't get context in Fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, fragment

I am absolute beginner for this, I'm sorry if this such a dumb mistakes.
so, I created fragment in which i have got recyclerView, but my recycler view is empty, i saw that my context is empty, and i think, that it can be the reason of this, i try to use getActivity

here is code of my fragment

```
package com.example.pocketcinema;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SearchFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerViewInterface {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerViewInterface rci;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
public List<String> nameOfFilm, youTubeUrl, photoUrl, descriptionToFilm, category;
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    recyclerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, 
false).findViewById(R.id.filmsList);
    rci = this;
    nameOfFilm = new ArrayList<>();
    youTubeUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    photoUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    descriptionToFilm = new ArrayList<>();
    category = new ArrayList<>();
   
    loadFilmsFromDB();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

}

private void loadFilmsFromDB() {
  Context context = requireContext();

    db.collection("films").get().addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() 
 {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                nameOfFilm.add(document.get("nameOfFilm").toString());
                descriptionToFilm.add(document.get("descriptionToFilm").toString());
                photoUrl.add(document.get("imageUrl").toString());
                youTubeUrl.add(document.get("videoURL").toString());
                category.add(document.get("category").toString());
   myAdapter =  new MyAdapter(context, nameOfFilm, descriptionToFilm, 
   photoUrl, youTubeUrl, 
   rci, category);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));


            }

        }
    });


}
```

here is screenshot with debuger, you can see that context = null

[context = null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6VsT.png)

here you can see that i set layout for recyclerView
[with logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKc1M.png)

here is Adapter

```
package com.example.pocketcinema;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context ct;
List<String> name, description, image, video, category;
private final RecyclerViewInterface recyclerViewInterface;

public MyAdapter(Context ct, List<String> nameOfFilm, List<String> 
descriptionOfFilm, List<String> imageUrl, List<String> videoUrl, 
RecyclerViewInterface rci,List<String> category) {
    name = nameOfFilm;
    description = descriptionOfFilm;
    image = imageUrl;
    video = videoUrl;
    this.ct = ct;
    recyclerViewInterface = rci;
    this.category = category;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ct);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view, recyclerViewInterface);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int 
position) {
    holder.nameFilm.setText(name.get(position));
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ct, PlayerActivity.class);

        }
    });
    Picasso.get().load(image.get(position)).into(holder.image2);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return image.size();
}


public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView nameFilm;
    ImageView image2;
    CardView cardView;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, RecyclerViewInterface 
 recyclerViewInterface) {
        super(itemView);
        nameFilm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
        image2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        



 itemView.findViewById(R.id.sectionOFRecyclerView).setOnClickListener 
 (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (recyclerViewInterface != null) {
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        recyclerViewInterface.onItemClick(pos);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }


}
}
```

[myAdapter isn't null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM8Mi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create an instance of activity as global variable. That means the context has not been generated yet.

Basically you can just use `requireContext()` method of Fragment class. This will provide you the context.

As I have mentioned in comment, you need to update your `onCreateView` method as below:

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
}
```

Then, you need to initialize your view and other stuff on `onViewCreated` method. You can update that method like this:

```java
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.filmsList);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.test);
    
    rci = this;
    nameOfFilm = new ArrayList<>();
    youTubeUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    photoUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    descriptionToFilm = new ArrayList<>();
    category = new ArrayList<>();
    
    loadFilmsFromDB();
}
```

**Notes**

- You don't have to send many string parameters to your adapter. It is better to create a Model class for that item, and send the list of that item. So, model classes will have all the data you need, and you can use them from that model. This will give you better coding style and will let you manage your data easier.
- To communicate with your XML layout, you can use [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) or [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) for that. This will also help you to use your view elements without creating variables for each of them.

Comment: thank you for answer, now i have valid context, but my recycler view still be empty, logcat show an issue:"RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Comment: Seems like you didn't add any layout manager for your recycler view. Try to add it on layout file or from the Java code.
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()));

Comment: strange, I did it in the method loadFilmFromDB in the last row of this method

Comment: Yes, I missed that. it is because when you initialize your adapter, you don't have any data inside of it. 
myAdapter =  new MyAdapter(context, nameOfFilm, descriptionToFilm, photoUrl, youTubeUrl, 
this, category);

when you create your adapter, your list shouldn't be empty. Basically, create your adapter after setting the list items. And if you can share adapter code, I can take a look if everything is fine with the adapter

Comment: yes, i edited post with adapter, by the way, before this i succesfully used recyclerView in main activity, than i decided to do it in the fragment, so I think that with adaptr is everything ok

Comment: but I think that myAdapter isn't null, beacouse in MainActivity it worked and debugger shows that when I adding myAdapter to recyclerView, it isn't null, now i'll add screen and you will see that

Comment: I'm very thankfull that you want to help me

Comment: okay, sorry for late answer. I haven't been with my computer. I have updated my code which is working fine on my tests. Let me know, if anything is wrong

Comment: wooow, it is working, thank you for support, I just use fragment first time, so I have so stange misstakes